# how to write a python worker that stays in memory processing jobs until the master thread kills it

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a worker node that reads data off of a queue to process images. The job loads from a redis queue and then a new thread is spun up to process the job. The jobs must process sequentially, I can't use parallization.  I need to use threads because for some reason memory is not fully released with the GPU, so this helps ensure memory the memory is released between threads. To load all the data to process the job is very expensive. I want to make processing faster and I can do that if the job parameters are similar.
The problem with this is it is slow to do it this way. To load a the data  into memory takes about 15 seconds. So that means every thread is loading the data, processing, then killing the thread and repeating. If the main job queue looks like this: [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 ]
I could save time by continuing to reuse the older thread before killing it because the main data for the thread is the same for all 1's, its only when I go from 1 to 2 that I really need to kill the thread and reload.

This is my currently working, but slow code:

```
def process_job(job):
    pass


message = r.brpop(list_name)
    j = json.loads(message[1])
    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_job, args=(j,))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

I tried to rewrite it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
while True:
    # Read from the redis queue
    message = r.blpop(list_name)
    job = json.loads(message[1])

    # Parse the JSON string and get the 'name' field
    model_name = job['model_id']
    # Check if we already have a thread for this name
    if model_name in threads:
        # Update the target function of the existing thread
        thread = threads[model_name]
        thread.target = process_job
        # Start the thread with the new arguments
        thread.start(job)
    else:
        # Create a new thread and start it
        for name, thread in threads.items():
            thread.join()
        #    del threads[name]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=process_job, args=(job,))
        thread.start()
        threads[model_name] = thread
```

How can I rewrite this so I don't kill the thread if the model_id is the same between job requests?

Comment: All Python threads within a Process share a memory space, so I don't see how killing a thread would affect memory use.  What does this mean: "The jobs must process sequentially, I can use parallization."  That seems to be contradictory.  If the jobs must process sequentially, that means you can't process them in parallel.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand pythons [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module, what definitely will not work is this whole business of changing the running threads target with something like `thread.start(job)`.

I would use [`Events`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) and [`Locks`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) from the same library, similar to this:

```py
from threading import Thread, Event, Lock

def process_job():
    pass

def process_job_thread_wrapper(job):
    global changingData, changingDataLock, changingDataEvent
    
    while True:
        changingDataEvent.clear()
        changingDataLock.acquire()
        process_job(changingData)
        changingDataLock.release()
        print("Processing job: {}".format(job.jobElement))
        # wait for main thread to provide new work
        changingDataEvent.wait()
        

r = RedisSomething
list_name = 'jobs'
threads = {}

changingData = None
changingDataLock = Lock()
changingDataEvent = Event()

while True:
    # Read from the redis queue
    message = r.blpop(list_name)
    job = json.loads(message[1])

    # Parse the JSON string and get the 'name' field
    model_name = job['model_id']
    # Check if we already have a thread for this name
    if model_name in threads:
        # Update the changingData
        changingDataLock.acquire()
        # only put the changed data in this
        changingData = job
        changingDataLock.release()
        changingDataEvent.set()
    else:
        # Create a new thread and start it
        for name, thread in threads.items():
            thread.join()
        #    del threads[name]
        threads[model_name] = Thread(target=process_job_thread_wrapper, args=(job))
        threads[model_name].start()
```

You can wait with your thread after finishing a job to update some changing data in the main thread. Then notify your thread that there is new data, without having to load it in its entirety. If I understood you correctly.